# Display message when conditionally not loading a bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Service class which is annotated with

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(...)
```

I'd like to display a custom message at startup to the service with something like

```
xxx Service is not being loaded
```

Is there a way to do this?  Since the bean isn't loaded, I can't used `@PostConstruct` or anything like that

Answer (score 1):

You could check all beans from `ApplicationContext` before init spring application and handle your logic if missing or found any instance

eg.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       System.out.println("Listing all beans");
       Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).stream().forEach(System.out::println);

       System.out.println("Listing all beans by type");
       Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(YourTypeBean.class)).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }

}
```